# How to determine the permutation parameters for a Turbo Code Interleaver?

Tags: forward-error-correction

In the 2004 paper [Designing good permutations for turbo codes: towards a single model](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.479.7859&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  it is mentioned you mention that :

"**turbo code permutation of DVB-RCS [5] and DVB-RCT [6] standards, which was devised by the authors of this article  was inspired by relations (11).**"

I believe this design knowledge was also used for DVB-RCS2 standard [ETSI EN 301 545-2 V1.3.1](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/301500_301599/30154502/01.03.01_60/en_30154502v010301p.pdf) (2020-07)

I would like to understand, out of all the possible permutation polynomials that could be used for a given payload length, how were the actual permutation control parameters : P, Q0, Q1, Q2 and Q3 found in Table A-1: Reference Waveforms for Linear Modulation Bursts of page 218 determined?

Document [ETSI TR 101 545-4 V1.1.1](https://(https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_tr/101500_101599/10154504/01.01.01_60/tr_10154504v010101p.pdf)) (2014-04) mentions on page 47 "The permutations (i.e. interleavers) between the component convolutional codes is based on simple algebraic laws, avoiding the use of memory-consuming look-up tables for the permutations. The laws are independent of the code rates and have been fine-tuned for each block size to avoid flattening of the error curve for BER above 10-9."

Where can I find information about this fine-tuning procedure? What is the meaning of **flattening of the error curve**?

Comment: "flattening of the error curve" probably means that a slight worsening of SNR should not lead to drastic worsening of BER.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure out an algorithm to obtain the parameters P,Q0,Q1,Q2 and Q3, but no success yet. The only thing I know is P cannot be a co-prime with the duo-binary length.

Flattening of the error curve means that if the permutation is not perfect, there will be some weak point in the payload and If a noise spike appears in that weak point it will create a packet loss. So the PER curve will flatten at high SNR to the horizontal asymptote equal to the probability of having a noise spike at this location.